# Comparing Strings in sql

Tags: sql, string, compare

I have data in the following format in my table in Column A and Column B.

```
Column A             Column B
12345678XY           1111111
12345678XYABCN00001  1111111
```

Using SQL, I need to make sure, whenever the in the two rows in Column A are in the above mentioned format, Column B should have the same number for each of them.

Could anyone kindly help me comparing the strings under Column A. I am not sure, how to approach this!!!

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, in fact, it is not even a question. When you say `the above mentioned format` - do you mean either 8 digits followed by two letters, or 8 digits followed by 6 letters followed by 5 digits? Which parts of the value will vary on different rows? Also, you will have to clarify what `I need to make sure` means. Do you need a query to report any rows breaking the rule? Do you need a way to prevent adding rows which break the rule? More details and examples would help us to help you.

Comment: Hi Turophile, sorry I was not clear. What I meant was, I compare two records where the first 10 characters in the first record is exactly the same in the first 10 characters in the second record. If that is the case, I need to find out, in Column B, I have the exact same number for both these records.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query which may help:

```
select *
from Table1 AS T1
inner join Table1 AS T2
on  left(T1.Column_A,10) = left(T2.Column_A,10)
where T1.Column_B <> T2.Column_B
```

You can see it running here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/129b1/1

Comment: Thank you so much Turophile :) I was able to get the result I wanted.